# delphi android, how to use JAttributeSet in init procedure?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I need to create a JEditText, so i found theses methods :

```
  JEditTextClass = interface(JTextViewClass)
    ['{A1E1255C-8FC9-449A-A886-57ABA315C3E3}']
    {class} function init(context: JContext): JEditText; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function init(context: JContext; attrs: JAttributeSet): JEditText; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function init(context: JContext; attrs: JAttributeSet; defStyleAttr: Integer): JEditText; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function init(context: JContext; attrs: JAttributeSet; defStyleAttr: Integer; defStyleRes: Integer): JEditText; cdecl; overload;
```

end;

but i can't understand how to set (and with what?)

```
attrs: JAttributeSet; 
defStyleAttr: Integer; 
defStyleRes: Integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the more flexible constructors are there for those who need them. If you don't know what to pass to them, perhaps you don't need them.

The [DPF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiandroid) code that wraps up an Android `EditText` uses the simplest constructor - see `TDPFJEditText.Create` in [DPF.Android.JEditText.pas](https://sourceforge.net/p/dpfdelphiandroid/code/HEAD/tree/DPF.Android.JEditText.pas).

Additionally, looking at [the Android documentation for `AttributeSet`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html), it would appear these tend to get created to represent attributes found in the XML definitions of Android resources, something we have no typical use of in Delphi Android apps.

I would suggest you use the simple constructor to create your object and then employ the various properties and methods of the created `EditText`. Don't get bogged down in the intricacies of the underpinnings of the resources that typically go to make up a Java Android app.